# SPFx create list item; 'InvalidClientQueryException'

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-list

Runing [this example](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud). i have a list("announcement2") in sharepoint online account and I am able to read items from that list. When I trigger create item event below;

```
private listItemEntityTypeName: string = "SP.Data.announcement2ListItem";
..

private createItem(): void {
    this.getListItemEntityTypeName()
      .then((listItemEntityTypeName: string): Promise<Response> => {
        const body: string = JSON.stringify({
          '__metadata': {
            'type': listItemEntityTypeName
          },
          'Title': `Item CREATED`
        });
        return this.props.httpClient.post(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`,
        SPHttpClientConfigurations.v1, {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata-version': ''
          },
          body: body
        }); 
      })
```

I see this exception in console Response content:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A type named 'SP.Data.announcement2ListItem' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."}}}
```

This looks about my "listItemEntityTypeName" property since I harcoded set it(if not set it its undefined). How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try `SP.Data.Announcement2ListItem` (check case sensitivity)?

Comment: @SergeiSergeev  You did it again! Thank you! please post it as answer and so I can mark it as answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `getListItemEntityTypeName` should return valid entity type name. You can try to investigate why it doesn't work as expected.

If you want to provide it manually you need to be careful because entity type parameter is case sensitive. So in your case it should be `SP.Data.Announcement2ListItem`

Comment: Yes in video example it returns entitytypename, somehow its not in mine, i am on this investigation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sergei, Please check this post when you have time; http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205906/setstate-can-only-update-a-mounted-or-mounting-error-in-web-part thank you

Comment: @TyForHelpDude: I saw that, but I'm not a react fan, so can't help here..